# Android: Force close onclick button listview

Tags: android

When i click the button i have an exeption and force close

Adapter code:

```
public class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

private ArrayList<produit> produits;
private LayoutInflater myInflater;

public myAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<produit> _produits) {
    this.myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.produits = _produits;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.produits.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.produits.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (null == convertView) {
        convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
    }

    Button btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), Local.class);
            v.getContext().startActivity(i);

        }
    });
    // set the text
    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(produits.get(position).nom);
    return convertView;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.v("bonjour", "Row button clicked");
}

}
```

main code :

```
public class Main extends Activity {


 private ArrayList<produit>produits=new ArrayList<produit>();


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    produits.add(new produit("marlboro"));
    produits.add(new produit("sabrine"));

    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    myAdapter adpt = new myAdapter (this,produits);

    list.setAdapter(adpt);

}
}
```

Logcat:

03-22 09:52:51.188: E/AndroidRuntime(480): ERROR: thread attach failed
03-22 09:52:52.259: E/AndroidRuntime(488): ERROR: thread attach failed
03-22 09:52:54.388: W/dalvikvm(495): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
03-22 09:52:54.388: E/AndroidRuntime(495): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {wassim.list/wassim.list.Local}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2749)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2855)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at wassim.list.myAdapter$1.onClick(myAdapter.java:63)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-22 09:52:54.408: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-22 09:57:54.618: W/InputManagerService(51): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 495 uid 10030

How can I make this work?

Comment: post your log cat also..

Comment: what is the exception mr.Wassim?

Comment: i think `v.getContext()` create prblm change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
private ArrayList<produit> produits;
private LayoutInflater myInflater;
private Context context

public myAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<produit> _produits) {
    this.myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.produits = _produits;
    this.context  = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return this.produits.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return this.produits.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

if (null == convertView) {
    convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
}

Button btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Local.class);
        context.startActivity(i);

    }
});
// set the text
TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText(produits.get(position).nom);
return convertView;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Log.v("bonjour", "Row button clicked");
}
}
```

Comment: you find the Logs in my question above

Comment: Did you declared activity in android manifest? Unable to find explicit activity class {wassim.list/wassim.list.Local}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: Are you sure you're getting the right context here?

```
Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), Local.class);
```